# Phirehose Setup Problems

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

Trying to use the Phirehose class from https://github.com/fennb/phirehose

After uploading everything to the server, when i try to run sample.php i get the following errors.  I've tried to manually run through the code but can't get to the bottom of this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Phirehose: Connecting to twitter stream: http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json with params: array (  'delimited' => 'length',)
Phirehose: Resolved host stream.twitter.com to 199.59.148.138
Phirehose: Connecting to 199.59.148.138
Phirehose: Connection established to 199.59.148.138
Phirehose: HTTP failure 1 of 20 connecting to stream: HTTP ERROR :  (). Sleeping for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are multiple different versions of the script.  The .zip availble for phirehose in githubs download section is a different version than just copying down the most recent version of the script.

Most recent version of the script appears to work perfectly.